# the conductor of unramıfied abelian extension

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $L/K$ be an unramified abelian extension. I want to show that its conductor is (1). To do this, I need to show the following two facts hold:

- (1) is divisible by all primes of $K$ that ramify in $L$.
- For all $\alpha\in K^*$ with $\alpha \equiv 1$ mod $(1)$,  $((\alpha),L/K)=1$
  where $(.,L/K)$ is the Artin map.

Ok, since there is no ramified primes, first condition is satisfied. But, I have problem at the second condition. How can we ensures that  $((\alpha),L/K)=1$. My attempt: Write $(\alpha)=\prod_\mathfrak{p} \mathfrak{p}^{n_\mathfrak{p}}$. Then $((\alpha),L/K)=\prod_\mathfrak{p} \sigma_\mathfrak{p}^{n_\mathfrak{p}}$ where $\sigma_\mathfrak{p}$`s are Frobenius element at $\mathfrak{p}$. Now I expect the Frobenius elements to be identity. I would be grateful, if anyone enlighten me.

Comment: Which results of class field theory are you allowed to use?

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer I am at beginner level in class field theory. I looked at Artin Reciprocity, Takagi Existence theorem, also I know that any prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of $K$  splits completely  in $L$ iff $(\mathfrak{p},L/K)=1$.

Comment: Then you need to prove the conductor-discriminant formula, which tells you that the conductor divides the discriminant. In class field theory, you rarely get results for free.

Comment: In general to find the kernel of the Artin map, we need to embed $L(E)/k(E)$ into a cyclotomic extension $L(\zeta_m)/k(E)$ for some $E$ not changing the structure of $L/k$ and $m$ chosen such that $\mathfrak{p}_i$ split completely in $k(E)$, see [there](https://amathew.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/the-proof-of-artins-lemma/) and [p.216-219](https://www.google.fr/search?q=Lang+algebraic+number+theory+pdf) of Lang. @franzlemmermeyer Could you help, I'm trying to construct a relevant example of $\zeta_m,E$ with say $k = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n), L = k(c^{1/n})$ ?